# What does the Laravel string validator actually test for?

Tags: laravel, validation

I presumed that the Laravel string validator worked similar to PHP's string sanitization filter, http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php.  In particular, I thought it would remove tags, but upon testing it I find this is not the case.  This raises a few interesting points:

- What does the string rule test for?  (Simply that the value is not an array, perhaps?)
- Why does it not filter tags?  Perhaps because (by default) tags are escaped by blade?
- What filter would I use if I wanted to strip tags?  My own or a regex?

In general, it would be good to know more about the specifics of how each Laravel rule works.  It's hard to work out from the code.  Any additional resources would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What does the string rule test for? (Simply that the value is not an array, perhaps?)**

It's checking native PHP's [`is_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-string.php) on the value.

**Why does it not filter tags? Perhaps because (by default) tags are escaped by blade?**

No, it's merely validating a value, not filtering a value.

**What filter would I use if I wanted to strip tags? My own or a regex?**

You can use the built in **e** function to escape a string, but you don't usually need it as blade already did it for you if you use the double curly brackets `{{$value}}`.

---

If you would love to learn what the function is doing, you can check the file `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Validation/Concerns/ValidatesAttributes.php`. It includes all the validation rules there and you can inspect what the validation rules are doing.

For `string` rule, it's calling [this code block](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/fcd2b9eea3d7a7b610d792deed82d1e82437eec0/src/Illuminate/Validation/Concerns/ValidatesAttributes.php#L1316-L1319):

```
/**
 * Validate that an attribute is a string.
 *
 * @param  string  $attribute
 * @param  mixed   $value
 * @return bool
 */
public function validateString($attribute, $value)
{
    return is_string($value);
}
```

Which, it's just a native [`is_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-string.php), and from the PHP docs:

```
is_string(false) = bool(false)
is_string(true) = bool(false)
is_string(NULL) = bool(false)
is_string('abc') = bool(true)
is_string('23') = bool(true)
is_string(23) = bool(false)
is_string('23.5') = bool(true)
is_string(23.5) = bool(false)
is_string('') = bool(true)
is_string(' ') = bool(true)
is_string('0') = bool(true)
is_string(0) = bool(false)
```